# generics with a T type and a named function type that takes T

Tags: go, generics

I have a module that defines a bunch of types

```
type Thing1 struct {}

type Thing2 struct {}
```

and named functions types that take the types above as arguments

```
type T1 func(t *Thing1)
type T2 func(t *Thing2)
```

Then it defines a map using these function types

```
var (
    ModThing1 = map[string]T1{ ... }
    ModThing2 = map[string]T2{ ... }
)
```

In my app that uses this module, I would like use a generic for `Thing1` and `Thing2`

Something like:

```
func do[T any](in *T, inMap map[string]func(in *T)) {
  for _, val := range inMap {
     val(in)
  }
}
...
do[mod.Thing1](&mod.Thing1{}, mod.ModThing1)
```

Of course the problem is that Go wont allow this because the type of the value of the map is not the same as `mod.ModThing1` value type.  `func(in *T))` vs `mod.T1`

Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

In the function `do`, declare an additional type parameter `F` with an approximated constraint that also references `T`. You take advantage of `T1` and `T2` having similar underlying types. You don't even have to explicitly instantiate `do`'s type arguments, both can be inferred.

```
func main() {
    do(&foo.Thing1{}, foo.ModThing1)
    do(&foo.Thing2{}, foo.ModThing2)
}

func do[T any, F ~func(*T)](in *T, inMap map[string]F) {
    for _, val := range inMap {
        val(in)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/wiWWzXVDG7v

---

If you have control over the imported package, another solution is to use a generic function type instead of `T1` and `T2`. The principle behind this abstraction is the same. In fact, here you can see more clearly why the first solution works:

```
type F[T any] func(t *T)

// instead of
// type T1 func(t *Thing1)
// type T2 func(t *Thing2)
```

Then you declare the map variables with specific instantiations of `F[T]`:

```
var (
    ModThing1 = map[string]F[Thing1]{ ... }
    ModThing2 = map[string]F[Thing2]{ ... }
)
```

Then in the `do` function you instantiate `F` with the type parameter:

```
func do[T any](in *T, inMap map[string]F[T]) {
    for _, val := range inMap {
        val(in)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/ITBqiqjjVUz

---

By the way, you can also abstract the map type:

```
type M[T any] map[string]F[T]

func do[T any](in *T, inMap M[T]) {
    for _, val := range inMap {
        val(in)
    }
}
```